# Angular - Animation initialization with ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

My current angular version is: 4.2.6

I am using angular's animation dsl to animate the opening of a modal component. The component is nested within another component that is shown/hidden using an `*ngIf`.

Here is a basic overview of the structure of the page:

```
<parent-wrapper>

  <div class="panel" *ngIf="toggle">
    <child-component>
      <!-- Form Stuff -->
      <modal-component active="modalActive"></modal-component>
    </child-component>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" *ngIf="toggle2">
    <child-component>
      <!-- Form Stuff -->
      <modal-component active="modalActive"></modal-component>
    </child-component>
  </div>

</parent-wrapper>
```

When the page loads the toggle values are false. During this time logging shows that the components get initialized yet are not added to the DOM.

When I set one of the toggles to true it renders the component in the DOM yet the animation styles for the modal component are not properly initialized which prevents the animation from working properly. The modal functions as expected yet it does not animate.

This is what I'm seeing in my inspector (modal component initialized with the input "inactive" for the animation):

```
<app-modal class="ng-tns-c21-7" ng-reflect-active="inactive">
  <div class="app-modal ng-trigger ng-trigger-modalAnim">
```

If I move the modal component outside the `*ngIf` it initializes and is rendered to the DOM as expected and animates just fine.

This is what it looks like properly initialized (modal component initialized with the input "inactive" for the animation):

```
<app-modal class="ng-tns-c21-7" ng-reflect-active="inactive">
  <div class="app-modal ng-trigger ng-trigger-modalAnim" style="z-index: 999; opacity: 1; display: block; transition: all;">
```

It's important that the modal be packaged with the child component so moving it to another location is not an option.

What is preventing those styles from being applied to the modal DOM when the modal component is rendered from an `*ngIf`?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but a work around is to use [hidden] instead.

Comment: I thought about that, but the panel portion that uses the ngIf is part of an internal library component that I can't change without impacting multiple of our apps. So unfortunately it's not an option.

Comment: try adding :host {display: block;} to your modal's styles.